# How can I generate any generic type at runtime on AOT platforms?

Tags: c#, ios, generics, aot

I need to generate generic types at runtime on AOT platforms. I know of a "workaround" that hints the compiler to generate a specific generic class by creating a dummy method in the code:

```
public void DoDummy(){
    var a1 = new MyClass<MyType>();
}
```

Unfortunately, this specific workaround will not work for me as I have over a few hundred thousand (no exaggeration) possible combinations of types that could be created.

Is there any way to accomplish what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not a perfect solution, I found that something better than a brute force list of all combinations (the normal workaround) can be achieved with a generic interface and a generic abstract class.

Create a generic class, such as this:

```
public abstract class GenericBase<T>
{
    public static bool AOTConstruct()
    {
        bool b = (new GV<T>() == null); // Where GV<T> is a Generic Class.
        // Do similar for all Generic Classes that need to be AOT compiled.
        return b;
    }
}
```

Then create a generic interface, such as this:

```
public interface IGenericValue<T>
{
    GenericBase<T> ConstructGenericBase();
}
```

Now, System Types can be AOT compiled for the Generic classes listed in AOTConstruct by being declared as the type for a class implementing the interface, like so:

```
public class SystemTypes : IGenericValue<float> // Implement IGenericValue for other Types.
{
    GenericBase<float> IGenericValue<float>.ConstructGenericBase()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The same can be done for any custom class, either in the same class as the System Types, or as part of the custom class' declaration (which I prefer for clarity).

It is disappointing to have to update the SystemTypes for new System-level Types to support, and to update the AOTConstruct for new Generic Classes that need support, but it works for compiling to iOS and does not require all combinations to be listed.

Comment: I know this is an older question and answer, but is the benefit here that you can list all of the open generic types in `AOTConstruct`, abstracting them away from the type parameters which are then specified by implementing the interface? Since interfaces now allow default implementations (and `ConstructGenericBase` is never meant to be called anyway), it seems that the interface implementation could be simplified now (unless I've misunderstood something). You would still need to explicitly list every generic type, but maybe a source generator could help there?

Comment: Yes, I think (haven't tested it myself) that a default interface implementation for `IGenericValue.ConstructGenericBase` could simplify `SystemTypes` to merely implement all generic implementations of the interface without having to explicitly define its own `ConstructGenericBase` implementations. That may also be able to be done with a source generator, although I do not know how to personally do that.

Comment: Using other recent C# features, such as generic attributes, it may be possible to have a generic attribute class have the `ConstructGenericBase` method instead of containing it within an interface. Then `GenericBase<T>` could be decorated with attributes that are fulfilled with the required generics. That would put both the generic classes (listed in `AOTConstruct`) and their generic parameters (as generic parameters to the decorating attributes) together for easier maintainence.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand what you want to do, but maybe this helps you:

```
private static object Create(Type genericType, params Type[] genericArguments)
{
    Type genericClass = genericType.MakeGenericType(genericArguments);
    return Activator.CreateInstance(genericClass);
}
```

This method creates all the needed generic type arguments for the `genericType` you want to create and creates an instance of the resulting type by using its parameterless constructor.

If you have a class like

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
}
```

and want to instantiate it with `string` as type argument you could call it like that:

```
var myinstance = Create(typeof(MyClass<>), typeof(string));
```

Note that if you want to use the return value (`myinstance`) efficiently you should probably declare it as `dynamic`.

Comment: Hi René, thanks for your answer. This is what I'm doing but the problem is that on AOT platforms if the generic type being created has not been declared anywhere in the program, an ExecutionEngineException will be thrown. So for example, if I create a MyClass<string> using MakeGenericType and nownere have I declared "MyClass<string>" anywhere in my code, it won't work. If I add "MyClass<string>" to the dummy method I posted in my question then it will work.

Comment: Ah ok, didn't know that. No experience here with AOT platforms. Sorry I couldn't help you.

Comment: @Rafael I am facing the same issue now. How could you solve this at the end?